# Resize drawn Rectangle using MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

I created a simple program which draw Rectangle to canvas using MVVM Pattern. Then i need to resize the drawn rectangle

I've been searching for a code how to resize it then i found this blog

```
https://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/
```

This blog shares the Solution so i download it.

then Implemented in my code

this is my xaml

```
<Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RectItems, Source={x:Static local:Vm.instance}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Transparent" Height="{Binding ElementName=window}" Width="{Binding ElementName=window}" >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseDownEvent" TargetObject="{x:Static local:Vm.instance}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseMoveEvent" TargetObject="{x:Static local:Vm.instance}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent" TargetObject="{x:Static local:Vm.instance}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Canvas>

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

This is my model

```
public class RectItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _x;
        public double X
        {
            get { return _x; }
            set
            {
                _x = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("X");
            }
        }

        private double _y;
        public double Y
        {
            get { return _y; }
            set
            {
                _y = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Y");
            }
        }
        private double _width;
        public double Width
        {
            get { return _width; }
            set
            {
                _width = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Width");
            }
        }

        private double _height;
        public double Height
        {
            get { return _height; }
            set
            {
                _height = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Height");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

And this is my ViewModel

```
AdornerLayer aLayer;

        bool _isDown;
        bool _isDragging;
        bool selected = false;
        UIElement selectedElement = null;

        Point _startPoint;
        private double _originalLeft;
        private double _originalTop;
        //end of variable declaration for resizing

        public ObservableCollection<RectItem> RectItems { get; set; }
        private Point startPoint;
        public Vm()
        {
            RectItems = new ObservableCollection<RectItem>();
        }
        public void MouseDownEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
        }
        public void MouseMoveEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
                return;
            if (selected) return;

            var pos = Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);

            // Set the position of rectangle
            var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
            var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);

            // Set the dimenssion of the rectangle
            var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
            var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;


            if (RectItems.Count != 0)
            {
                var exist = RectItems.Where(xx => xx.X == x).LastOrDefault();
                if (exist != null)
                {
                    exist.Height = h;
                    exist.Width = w;
                }
                else
                {
                    RectItems.Add(new RectItem
                    {
                        X = x,
                        Y = y,
                        Height = h,
                        Width = w
                    });
                }
            }
            else
                RectItems.Add(new RectItem
                {
                    X = x,
                    Y = y,
                    Height = h,
                    Width = w
                });
        }
```

And this is my code for resizing

```
 public void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Remove selection on clicking anywhere the window
            if (selected)
            {
                selected = false;
                if (selectedElement != null)
                {
                    // Remove the adorner from the selected element
                    aLayer.Remove(aLayer.GetAdorners(selectedElement)[0]);
                    selectedElement = null;
                }
            }

            // If any element except canvas is clicked, 
            // assign the selected element and add the adorner
            if (e.Source != sender as Canvas)
            {
                _isDown = true;
                _startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);

                selectedElement = e.Source as UIElement;

                _originalLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(selectedElement);
                _originalTop = Canvas.GetTop(selectedElement);

                aLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(selectedElement);
                aLayer.Add(new ResizingAdorner(selectedElement));
                selected = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Selected Value: " + selected);
        }
```

From the solution i found on the blog. I removed all the code in code behind and i leave this

```
// Handler for element selection on the canvas providing resizing adorner
        void myCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Remove selection on clicking anywhere the window
            if (selected)
            {
                selected = false;
                if (selectedElement != null)
                {
                    // Remove the adorner from the selected element
                    aLayer.Remove(aLayer.GetAdorners(selectedElement)[0]);                    
                    selectedElement = null;
                }
            }

            // If any element except canvas is clicked, 
            // assign the selected element and add the adorner
            if (e.Source != myCanvas)
            {
                _isDown = true;
                _startPoint = e.GetPosition(myCanvas);

                selectedElement = e.Source as UIElement;

                _originalLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(selectedElement);
                _originalTop = Canvas.GetTop(selectedElement);

                aLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(selectedElement);
                aLayer.Add(new ResizingAdorner(selectedElement));
                selected = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

The controls drawn can be resized from top, left, right button.

But on my code. When i resize it from the top left.

it doesn't resize it from there. What it does it adjust the width and height. Not the TOP Left of the Rectangle

Here is the drawn Rectangle

[image]

And this is what happens when i resize it from the top. It resize the bottom right not the top left

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. You found a seemingly working solution on the internet. Then you removed parts of it so that it now doesn't work any more. Why don't you put the removed parts back in place?

Comment: hi @Clemens i removed the other part in order to find for the problem. But i can't solve it. I also removed all the method in the Solution i downloaded  and leave the myCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown in order to check if the resize is working, and it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `ResizingAdorner` class if you have used it without any modifications. The class directly modifies the size and `Canvas` coordinates of the associated element, regardless of your bindings. This means when you drag the top left corner, the size of the element is properly changed (because the `Width` and `Height` properties are modified), but the code then tries to set `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Right` which doesn't work, because the whole `Rectangle` is inside a `ContentPresenter` (which is the item container for `ItemsControl`). Only the `ContentPresenter` can actually influence the position as it is a direct child of `Canvas`. Setting `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Right` on the `Rectangle` has no effect, because there is no `Canvas` that could access those values.

To fix this, you have to get hold of the `RectItem` instance inside the `ResizingAdorner` class - probably using `DataContext`:

```
var rectItem = adornedElement.DataContext as RectItem;
```

And now you can modify the `rectItem` properties instead of all existing references to `Width`, `Height`, `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` in the `ResizingAdorner` class.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't realize that that is the problem. and thank you for your explanation